# Silverlight application with external web service references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, wcf, web-services

I have a standalone Silverlight 4 application that has a service reference from a WCF project different from the web site where the SL object is stored (used). The service url are hardcoded  and the web site where my SL object is stored (used) was not generated using the project wizard (in which you create the Silverlight project and its web site). 
So, my questions are:

- how could I stop using hardcoded url values from SL?(from the
  serviceReference.client file)
- how could I fix the Wcf service port value? (everytime it chooses a different port value: like localhost:randomPort/... to keep the randomPort fixed )?
- how can I debug the SL project once it is loaded? (followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798210/how-do-i-debug-my-silverlight-4-application) but it keeps throwing the error **2104 unable to download the silverlight client. check your web server settings**)

Answer (score 0):

For Hardcoded URLs:

`var serviceClient = new YourServiceReference.ServiceClient();
 serviceClient.Endpoint.Address=new EndpointAddress("http://yourservice.com/Service.svc");`

How could I fix the Wcf service port value?

In WCF Project properties go to WEB ->Servers -> Use Visual Studio Development Server ->Specific Port [add port you want] or you can setup your service on your local IIS